# ¿Como detector una click o un redirecionamiento en una pagina hijo?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando detectar cualquier acción que se haga en la pagina hijo. Algun click o direccionamiento.

**Codigo**

```
  <button id="botonTabOpen">Abrir</button>
  <button id="botonTabClose">Cerrar</button>
  <script>
    var miVentana;

    function window_open(){
      miVentana = window.open( "http://google.com/", "_blank");
    }


    function window_close(){
      miVentana.close();
    }

    document.getElementById("botonTabOpen").onclick = function() {window_open()};

    document.getElementById("botonTabClose").onclick = function() {window_close()};



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

He probado con addEventListener pero no lo pude logar

Answer (score 0):

A esta altura un popup no te dejará escuchar a sus eventos a menos que sea del mismo origen. Por ejemplo si abres un popup vacío y le inyectas contenido, los listeners sobre éstos son capturados por el documento padre.

```
var w;
jQuery('#testing').click(function() {
  w = window.open('', "", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");

  $(w.document.body)
  .append('<a id="linkinterior" href="#prueba">click para probar</a>')
  .click(function(event) {
    $('#msg').text('se detecta click hacia: ' + $(event.target).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/4yLruhj5/28/

Si cargas google en tu popup cualquier intento de manipular o revisar el popup te bloqueará por cross-origin frame.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo piensas bien, es peligroso que se comportara de otra manera. Sería sencillo poner un link a tu banco y escuchar el submit de tu login para saber tus credenciales. Sería el phishing perfecto.